# IronPython always in 32-bit mode on 64bit machine even when running ipy64.exe

Tags: ironpython, 32bit-64bit

I am sure I am missing something simple but unfortunately a lot of searching hasn't thrown up what it is..

I am running Windows 7 64-bit (I verified this by looking at Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > System and seeing that it says 64-bit Operating System).

I have IronPython 2.7.3 installed from here (http://ironpython.codeplex.com/downloads/get/423690)

This has created the following shortcut (with no corresponding shortcut in C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7...):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\ipy64.exe"

If I run this, I get this prompt:

```
"c:\Projects>"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\ipy64.exe"
IronPython 2.7.3 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.296 (32-bit)
```

The docs from an older version of IronPython (2.6) at http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/27350 say that:

"A very visible new feature added to this release is that ipy.exe is now strictly a 32-bit only assembly. That is, it gets executed as a 32-bit CLR process on both x86 and x64 operating systems. ipy64.exe, despite what its name might imply, is a platform agnostic assembly matching the old behavior of ipy.exe in the sense that it gets executed as a 32-bit process on 32-bit OSes and 64-bit on 64-bit OSes."

From this, I infer that ipy64 should have started as a 64 bit process, but that's not what shows in the prompt.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance..

Edited to add: I have also tried running the following in the IronPython shell, which I found from another question on this site, to check whether the OS is 64 bit

```
>>> import System
>>> System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
True
```

... but then I ran the following which indicates that IronPython really is running in 32 bit mode.

```
>>> import System
>>> System.IntPtr.Size
4
```

Comment: Do you have the 64-bit version of .Net 4 installed?

Comment: I think so based on a couple of my Visual Studio projects. How do I tell? Apologies, I'm a bit of a VS novice.

Comment: It's in program files (x86) - that is the location for 32-bit applications in 64bit windows isn't it?  Do you have the problem if you copy and run ipy64 somewhere else, e.g. regular program files?

Comment: I tried copying it to C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7 and running it - didn't think this would work because the executable is the same, and indeed it returned the same results "IronPython 2.7.3 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.296 (32-bit)"

Comment: I just created a ConsoleApplication in Visual Studio that contained Console.WriteLn(System.IntPtr.Size) and the output is "8". I presume that means I have 64-bit .NET installed

Comment: The output of corflags indicates that ipy64.exe is not 32 bit- 
`ILONLY    : 1`
`32BIT     : 0`
`Signed    : 1`

Comment: Also, in task manager, the process is listed as "ipy64.exe *32"

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out that the shell which you use to run IronPython matters. 
The 32 bit dos command shell exists in C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe whereas the 64 bit dos command shell exists in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
(See below screenshots)

[32 bit dos command shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMD5t.jpg)
[64 bit dos command shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1wzI.jpg)